# Zf2, Ussing expression in identifier in Where\In

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I try use expression in identifier in `where->in`.

For example SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(created) IN ('2014-03-05','2013-06-07')
```

I tried use it:

```
$days = ['2014-03-05','2013-06-07'];
$where = new Where();
$where->addPredicate(new Predicate\In(new Expression('DATE(created)'), $days));
$select->where($where);
```

It's not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still couldn't find the solution via the `Predicate\In` but found something that could be used to make it run -

```
$days = array('2014-08-07', '2014-08-08');

$platform = $this->tableGateway->adapter->getPlatform();
$predicateIn = 'DATE('.$platform->quoteIdentifierChain(array('created')).')';
$predicateIn .= " in (";
$predicateIn .= $platform->quoteValueList($days);
$predicateIn .= ")";
$select->where(array($predicateIn));
```

Sql query formed is -

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE(created) in ('2014-08-07', '2014-08-08')`

Will definitely let you know if I could find the required solution.